# Interpolation of quaternion orientations and vector positions

Tags: math, 3d, camera, geometry

I have a camera in 3d space that is defined by quaternion and position vector (q1 and p1)
I want to move camera to another viewpoint defined by another pair of quaternion and vector (q2 and p2). To achieve smooth animation I interpolate quaternions using spherical linear interpolation and position vectors using linear interpolation. For small camera movements it works ok, but if camera should orbit around model on 180 degrees it looks ugly, because it doesn't orbit model, but goes through it.

So the question is how to interpolate camera position taking into account slerp interpolation of camera orientation?

Comment: Then, maybe you want to interpolate focus point instead of camera position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem:

Firstly I calculate difference between quaternions q1 and q2 and calculate axis-angle representation from this difference. Then I calculate rotation centre from line p1-p2, rotation axis and angle value:

center = (p1 + p2) * 0.5 + norm(axis X (p2 - p1)) * (0.5 * |p2 - p1| / sin(angle * 0.5) )

and then I just rotate point p1 around center to interpolate camera position